# SSRS 2008 Dataset Filtering - SUM / Break down by month

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset that is going to get passed to an SSRS report that looks like this:

```
CODE TEXT COUNT  MONTH 
100  ABC  20     January 
100  ABC  10     February
200  DEF  15     January 
200  DEF  15     February
300  GHI  0      x 
400  JKL  10     January
```

This 'x' indicates there is no data for that code/text for the current year, however, I still need it to display. In SSRS I want to have a column to display for the current month (February) and a column to display for year to date:

```
    CODE TEXT MONTH_TO_DATE YEAR_TO_DATE
    100  ABC  10            30   [20 + 10]
    200  DEF  15            30   [15 + 15]
    300  GHI  0             0    [0] 
    400  JKL  0             10   [0 + 10]
```

Is this possible in SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to have to be done in SQL so it would be easier to adjust the SQL if you posted what you have already, rather than the data resulting from that SQL.

Anyway, we have to find a way to know it is the current month and display it, which we can do with the SQL `CASE` statement. Maybe you have a date field you can query which might be cleaner than below, but I'll just run with the data as you have provided (that is, we just have a month name which we compare to the current month using the `DATENAME` and `GETDATE` SQL functions - obviously this doesn't work if you have multiple years of data as every February will be aggregated into the current month, but you get the idea for what to do):

```
SELECT [CODE], [TEXT], 
    SUM(CASE WHEN [MONTH] = DateName(month, GetDate()) THEN [COUNT] END) AS CurrentMonth,
    SUM([COUNT]) AS YearToDate
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [CODE], [TEXT]
ORDER BY [CODE], [TEXT]
```

Now, in your comment on Vlad's answer you say you can't do a `SUM(COUNT(fieldname))` which you can actually do if you use nested queries, like so:

```
SELECT [CODE], [TEXT], SUM([COUNT]) AS Total
FROM ( -- This is a nested query
    SELECT [CODE], [TEXT], COUNT(somefield) AS [COUNT]
    FROM MyTable
)
GROUP BY [CODE], [TEXT]
ORDER BY [CODE], [TEXT]
```

If you want to display `x` for the zero values then use the following Format for the YearToDate cell:

```
#,##0;-#,##0;x
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I was able to use some of what you posted above combined with a few tweaks on my end to get my desired results. This should work a lot nice going into SSRS. Thank you and also thank you to all that responded to my question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in either SQL or SSRS - doing it in SQL (as described by Chris Latta) should be simpler and more efficient, but if that option is not available, here is how to do it in SSRS:

1. Add a 4-column table to the report, with the appropriate dataset.
2. Add a group (including group footer) on your `CODE` and `TEXT` columns to the table.
3. Add your `CODE` and `TEXT` values to the group footer.
4. Delete (or hide) the Details section row on your report.
5. Enter the following expression into the appropriate cell in the group footer row for the year-to-date column:

   `=Sum(Fields!COUNT.Value)`
6. Enter the following expression into the appropriate cell in the group footer row for the month-to-date column:

   `=Sum(iif(MonthName(DatePart("m",Now()))=Fields!MONTH.Value,Fields!COUNT.Value,0))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return this from the sql select/stored procedure. You should use a LEFT JOIN i think for those 0 results

Comment: Hi Vlad, I don't think I can do this with SQL. Currently my query combines 5 tables using a LEFT JOIN to get the 0's I already have. The column COUNT is already created by a COUNT(ColumnName). I tried adding another column in the SELECT clause to sum of the values in the COUNT column, [ SUM(COUNT(ColumnName)) as 'YearlyCount'] however SQL did not like that syntax.   If there is a way to do that, please let me know.

Comment: Perhaps it would help more if you posted your code. It is difficult to see just from the results. My general strategy would be to create a table for all possible codes, and then left join my results with that, leaving 0 or null for any missing month result.